# Solve $y' = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help with this $$y' = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x} + \sqrt[3]{y}$$
Tried making $t=\sqrt[3]{y}$. Then $3t^{2}t'_{x} = \frac{1}{2}x^\frac{1}{2} + t$.

$p=t'$. And then expressed $x$ and differentiated with respect to $t$. But can't see solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural thing to do first is to consider the transformation
$$\begin{align}u&=x^{1/2} \\ v&= y^{1/3}.\end{align}$$
Then,
$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dv}=\frac{2uy'}{3v^2}$$
and hence
$$y'=\frac{3v^2}{2u}\frac{dv}{du}.$$
Substituting in the original ODE yields to
$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^2+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right).$$
This is a simple [homogeneous ODE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) which can be solved easily by the standard trick of lettting $w=v/u$.